# Firebase Insert is happening instead of update, no error is shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update the fields in firebase database using react native and instead new entry is being inserted on the click of the button.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {  Platform, StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Text, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import {editAp} from '../pages/func';
import firebase from 'firebase';
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
 firebase.initializeApp({});
}
class Edit1 extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
    email:this.props.navigation.state.params.email,
    password:this.props.navigation.state.params.password,
    keyis:this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis,
 };
}
submit1=()=>{
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis)
    firebase.database().ref('/users1').child(this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis).update(({email:this.state.email,password:this.state.password}))
    Alert.alert('Action!', 'user updated');
}
render(){
  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Edit Here</Text>
            <TextInput style={{marginTop:20, height:40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1}} onChangeText={email=>this.setState({email})} value={this.state.email}/>
            <TextInput style={{marginTop:20, height:40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1}} onChangeText={password=>this.setState({password})} value={this.state.password}/>
            <TextInput style={{marginTop:20, height:40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1}} onChangeText={keyis=>this.setState({keyis})} value={this.state.keyis}/>
       <Button title='Submit' onPress={this.submit1} />
        </View>
    );
    }
}
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex:1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#fff',
 padding: 30,
 },
 });
 export default Edit1;
```

I am not knowing what's wrong with my update function email, password, keyis value i am getting on the textinput field as well as console, What is wrong in the submit1 function??
Structure of database is given below:

[image: Database Structure]

insert code:

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {  Platform, StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Text, TextInput, Alert, Button, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
if (!firebase.apps.length) {    firebase.initializeApp({}); }
class Form2 extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
   this.state = {
     email:'',
    password:'',
      };  }
   addNew = () => {
    firebase.database().ref('/users1').push({
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,

    });
    Alert.alert('Action!', 'user added');
    this.setState({
      email:'',
      password:'',
});  }
   render() {
  return(
<View style={styles.container}>
<Text style={styles.inpt}>Insert Ravel</Text>
<TextInput style={styles.inputBox1} underlinerColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
placeholder="Email"  onChangeText={e => { this.setState({  email: e,            });          }}     />
<TextInput style={styles.inputBox2} underlinerColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'  placeholder="password" 
onChangeText={e => { this.setState({ password: e,            });       }}   />
<View style={styles.button1}>
<Button title='Insert Record' onPress={this.addNew.bind(this)}/>
</View></View>  )   } }
export default Form2;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212893/discussion-on-question-by-chintan-bhuta-firebase-insert-is-happening-instead-of).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some id in the update code:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users1/'+userId)
```

so maybe firebase inserting new data because it don't know the id of rows to update

Comment: from where this userId I fetch, because already unique id is keyis and is written inside child and for they particular keyis(the unique id for each row in db) i want to update the email and password fields. Using following code: firebase.database().ref('/users1'+this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis).update(({email:this.state.email,password:this.state.password})) new value is inserted

Comment: @ChintanBhuta i forgot to add another slash. please try that new code

Comment: firebase.database().ref('/users1'/+this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis).update(({email:this.state.email,password:this.state.password})) so like this I should do?

Comment: with the above code it is inserting the new value into database instead of updating existing one @kafinsalim

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with mine:

**The Registration Part:**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {  Platform, StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Text, TextInput, Alert, Button, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
if (!firebase.apps.length) {    firebase.initializeApp({}); }
class Form2 extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
   this.state = {
     email:'',
    password:'',
      };  }
   addNew = () => {

    //MODIFIED PATH HERE
    firebase.database().ref('/users1/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({

      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,

    });
    Alert.alert('Action!', 'user added');
    this.setState({
      email:'',
      password:'',
});  }

//This will creating node with user UID as value
```

**Update Activity Code:**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {  Platform, StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Text, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import {editAp} from '../pages/func';
import firebase from 'firebase';
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
 firebase.initializeApp({});
}
class Edit1 extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
    email:this.props.navigation.state.params.email,
    password:this.props.navigation.state.params.password,
    keyis:this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis,
 };
}
submit1=()=>{
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis)

//Modified path here also

firebase.database().ref('/users1/').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update(({email:this.state.email,password:this.state.password}))
        Alert.alert('Action!', 'user updated');
    }
    render(){
      return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Edit Here</Text>
                <TextInput style={{marginTop:20, height:40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1}} onChangeText={email=>this.setState({email})} value={this.state.email}/>
                <TextInput style={{marginTop:20, height:40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1}} onChangeText={password=>this.setState({password})} value={this.state.password}/>
                <TextInput style={{marginTop:20, height:40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1}} onChangeText={keyis=>this.setState({keyis})} value={this.state.keyis}/>
           <Button title='Submit' onPress={this.submit1} />
            </View>
        );
        }
    }
     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
     flex:1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     backgroundColor: '#fff',
     padding: 30,
     },
     });
     export default Edit1;
```

All I have done is modified your data path.. I am assuming your user is registered as I cannot see any sign up thing in your registration code.

Just change the path. Rest of the code is same. This will create node with user UID instead of database ID. 
Let me know if it works. Don't forget to create new user.

Comment: error in currentUser. unexpected token, expected "," in that line in registration code

Comment: @ChintanBhuta please add `+` after `/users1/`.. I have editted my code as well.

Comment: @ChintanBhuta that line should now become: `ref('/users1/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)`

Comment: error in your code, I had got earlier too, this code doesnt work at all typeError: null is not an object(evaluating'_firebase.drfault.auth().currentUser.uid'). Something you need to change in firebase syntax for update query with key or child as its method this way isnt going to work

Comment: @ChintanBhuta where did that word `drfault` come from?? Just share google drive link here

Comment: @ChintanBhuta do you have Telegram?

Comment: @ChintanBhuta please message me on telegram

Comment: ohkk i will do it